# After SSL upgrading Wordpress admin area not loading properly

Tags: wordpress, ssl, admin

I googled a lot on Stackoverflow and all solution posted not worked for me.

After upgrading with SSL (and upgrading correctly the url from http to https) the admin area not loading properly, not only CSS but many things,like powerbuilder, galleries and so on. I tried adding:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

and

```
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

and

```
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

and all solutions found in many topics on stackoverflow, but the only results is that now the admin area loads the CSS but other things not, like this:

[image: wordpress image icons not loading, neither gallery or editor or other things]

I followed also this topic: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/236881/upgrade-to-ssl-breaks-admin-dashboard

tried also to disable mod_security by .htaccess but the situation is the same . Dunno really what can i do.

Other screenshot showing the panel Customization for the Theme, it's not loading anything.

[image]

My server is not a dedicated so my access is limited to investigate.

Comment: Have you tried reverted the changes to see if SSL is the problem?

Comment: hI Garth and thanks for helping. This will be my last solution, but 2 days ago i was working on same server without ssl and all worked.. the problem started when i upgraded the server with SSL. On frontsite all works perfectly. i guess if i reverse to http, admin area will come back ok..

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved. Was a Wordpress last version (4) bug. Upgrading to 5 all works correctly. i remember i installed this is just the day before the wordpress 5 release came out.